# How can you pack ObjectDB in a runnable JAR file?

Tags: java, jar, objectdb

I wanted to know if it is possible to include an ObjectDB database file `.odb` in a runnable JAR.

The method:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(path);
```

takes a String path as an argument and not a URL. This means that `getResource()` does not work. Neither do `getResource.getPath()` and `getResource.toString()` work, since they somehow show a distorted path name and during runtime the database file is created outside the jar file.

So I was wondering if it is possible for the  `.odb` file to be created inside the JAR and be manipulated within the JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you copy your resource to temporary folder using for instance:

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile()
```

(http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL,%20java.io.File%29)? And then you can use file path to copy.

Temporary system folder for current user you can find by:

```
File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
```

Answer (score 0):

An ObjectDB database must be a file and cannot be a resource within a file.

Following the solution of rsutormin seems as the right way to go.